# i cannot move a file into another directory; trying to move file princess.leia.txt into millenium_falcon; worked for me before but now im stumped

Tags: macos, terminal

The code that i've been trying; and nothing is happening. I just need to move the Princess leia text file to millenium falcon directory.

````
mv ~/rebellion/princess.leia.txt/millenium_falcon/princess.leia.txt
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mv ~/rebellion/princess.leia.txt ~/millenium_falcon/princess.leia.txt
```

Comment: this was the response:  ```mv: rename /Users/adelaidecraig/rebellion/princess.leia.txt to /Users/adelaidecraig/millenium_falcon/princess.leia.txt: No such file or directory```

Comment: does the directory `/Users/adelaidecraig/millenium_falcon` exist?

Comment: it renamed my whole directory when i tried moving it. newbie here. Thank you for the help